# problem with hiding ActionBar for specific Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-actionbar

in past 2 weeks i was working on The combination of TabLayout , viewPager , RecyclerView & fragment so here is the question.

i want to hide ActionBar for specific Fragment and i did it inside Fragment Class like this:

public class MA0FragmentWord extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

```
View v;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<MA0WordItems> mList;
private List<MA0WordItems> mlistFull;


public MA0FragmentWord(){
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_fragment0,container,false);

    recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.word_recycler0);

    MA0RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new MA0RecyclerAdapter(getContext(),mList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {


         @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            if (dy > 10) {
            // View view = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(0);
                ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();

            } else if (dy<0){

                ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
            }
        }

    });

    return v;
}
```

it seems like it works and it does but the problem is that my xml layout seems to have a bug and it has some kind of problem with rendering at the bottom of view. i changed to linear Layout as well but nothing changed (when the action bar hides the view goes top so the bottom of my view goes up as well and creates some white space),(sorry for bad English)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity0">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewPager0"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#d4d4d4"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#a6ae3d"
    app:tabTextColor="#d4d4d4">

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout0">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/word_recycler0"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 0):

for any one who got same problem as i did, i gave up on hiding action bar (it hides actually but with some problems that i explained...) so we can do some thing else , we can hide action bar from manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar">
```

and of curse we can hide/show action bars for specific activity like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity0"
        android:label="Lets Talk"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"></activity>
```

and we can easily access Main Activity elements from Fragment Activity and implement on scroll changes like this:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {


         @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            if (dy > 0) {
               TabLayout tabLayout =((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.tabLayout0);
               tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);




            } else if (dy<0){

                TabLayout tabLayout =((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.tabLayout0);
                tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

    });
```

so actually we don't have to hide/show action bars on scroll, we can use views  and implement elements indie of it and hide/ show it as i showed.
if u know any easier way to do it i would like to know that.